# How to make Netty client read entire response

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I have a Camel route that communicates with a COBOL server using a TCP socket connection. The route basically looks like this:

```
<route>
      <from uri="direct:sendMessage" />
      <log message="Sending message to server: ${body}" />
      <to uri="netty4:tcp://hostname:1234?requestTimeout=2000&amp;encoding=windows-1252" />
      <log message="Received response from server: ${body}" />
</route>
```

Calling this route results in the following exception:

```
Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-vmuxfusepoc01-34999-1467706512020-14-2 on ExchangeId: ID-vmuxfusepoc01-34999-1467706512020-14-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 1048576: 1008807217 - discarded

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[sendMessage       ] [to51              ] [direct:sendMessage                                                            ] [       697]
[sendMessage       ] [log60             ] [log                                                                           ] [         0]
[sendMessage       ] [to53              ] [netty4:tcp://jadev:7616?requestTimeout=2000&encoding=windows-1252             ] [       691]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-vmuxfusepoc01-34999-1467706512020-14-1
    ExchangePattern     InOut
    Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-vmuxfusepoc01-34999-1467706512020-14-2, CamelHttpMethod=POST, CamelHttpPath=, CamelHttpQuery=null, CamelHttpServletRequest=(POST /message)@927654619 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@374ae2db, CamelHttpServletResponse=HTTP/1.1 500 
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1

, CamelHttpUri=/message, CamelHttpUrl=http://localhost:8282/message, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, CamelServletContextPath=/message, Content-Length=690, Content-Type=null, Host=localhost:8282}
    BodyType            String
    Body                uid:dev2016070412325814024903532ºS:bookinfoºbkd0001:017953491ºcmn0001:wdedul01
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 1048576: 1008807217 - discarded
  at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.fail(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:501)[io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.failIfNecessary(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:477)[io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:403)[io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectDecoder.decode(ObjectDecoder.java:69)[io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:343)[io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:315)[io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:229)[io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)[io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)[io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:847)[io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)[io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)[io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)[io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)[io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)[io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.27.Final]
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)[io.netty:netty-common:4.0.27.Final]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_101]
```

After adding `textline=true` to the netty url the request is send correctly but only the first line of the servers response is returned by Netty to Camel. The server returns about 100 lines of text and then closes the connection.

I've tried using StringEncoder and StringDecoder but this gives me the same result as 'textline=true'.

**My question is:** How can I configure Netty to return the entire response of the server as a String. Message delimiters are of no concern because exactly 1 message will be returned before the connection is closed by the server.

Answer (score 0):

As you have no guarantee that the whole message will be read in one operation you will need to implement your own ByteToMessageDecoder which understand the used framing.